# Many-to-one SQL IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a MySQL table `read` that records a `userid` and an `articleid` that records what users have read what articles. I now want to list the users that have read articles `1`, `2` and `3`.

I know that the following is not possible, but it illustrates the idea:

```
SELECT id
FROM user 
WHERE (1,2,3) IN (SELECT articleid FROM `read` WHERE userid=user.id);
```

This should check that `1`, `2` and `3` exist as `articleid` in the table `read` for a specific `userid`. That is what I mean with a many-to-one IN statement.

Is there something I can use for this problem in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT userid
FROM read
WHERE articleid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT articleid) = 3;
```

Note:  If there are no duplicates in `read`, then use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT id
FROM user 
WHERE exists 
(
SELECT 1 FROM `read` WHERE userid=user.id
and articleid in (1,2,3)
having count(distinct articleid) = 3
);
```

For the given `userid` if only `1,2,3` should be the `articleid's` then

```
SELECT id
FROM user 
WHERE exists 
(
SELECT 1 FROM `read` WHERE userid=user.id
having count(case when articleid in (1,2,3) then 1 end)= count(*)
);
```